# Tailwind error during build with vue project

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, postcss

My Vue2 Tailwind CSS project is running well in dev. But for production I still have an issue :

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=production && npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/styles/index.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css --minify && vue-cli-service build

(node:19240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
```

I tryed to use PostCSS8 and also the Compat 7 Version that are mentionned in many stackoverflow posts, but this absolutely does nothing.

Any way to make it works under Vue 2 ?

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build:local": "SET NODE_ENV=production && npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/styles/index.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css --minify && vue-cli-service build",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production && npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/styles/index.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css --minify && vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "tldts": "^5.7.38",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.7.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try all of these 4 "solutions" does not work : https://exerror.com/error-postcss-plugin-tailwindcss-requires-postcss-8/

Answer (score 0):

i'm having the same issue.
If you install tailwind compat version at 2.1.4 it will work, but i need some fixes and functionalities added later.
For you to try this fix, change on your package.json

```
- "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.7"
+ "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "2.1.4",
```

If someone can get it to work above 2.1.4 please respond here.